# bind function in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a component in React and I'm using some function in it 
e.g.

```
class A {
   changeDid(e) {

  }
   render() {
    return (
      <input type="text" onChange{this.changeDid.bind(this)}>
    )
  }
}
```

I want to understand a line this.changeDid.bind(this) 
can anyone help me on this ??

Answer (score 3):

> The [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

`this.changeDid.bind(this)` means that in `changeDid` `this` will be refer to `A`, so you can get methods that related to `A`.

```
class A {
  changeDid(e) {
     this.someMethod();
  }

  someMethod() {
    // ... 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input type="text" onChange={this.changeDid.bind(this)}>
    )
  }
}
```

but if you pass to `onChange={ this.changeDid }`, `this` will refer to global scope (in browser it is `window`, or `undefined` if you use [`strict mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)), and previous example will not work, because `someMethod` exists in `A` but not in `window`

Answer (score 1):

I've created a simple example for you.

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    this.state = {
      item : 'hello World'
    }
    /* this.click = this.click.bind(this) */
  }
  click(){
     console.log(this)
     console.log(this.state.item)
  }
    render(){
    return <div>
       <button onClick={this.click}>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  }
}

React.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

So if you click on a button you will get next in `console` :

```
 console.log(this) // undefined 
 console.log(this.state.item) // Type Error, Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

That's occurs because inside `click` method `this` links to the `undefined`, but we want to display our `states`.

How can you fix it? To make sure that we get correct context inside `click` method we `bind(this)` it. remove comments from this line `/* this.click = this.click.bind(this) */` and you will get correct behavior of your method.

Worked example [***fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/283/)

I hope it will help you.

Thanks.